# Multiple docker images run from docker file

Tags: docker

I am trying to execute multiple docker images run from single docker file with different ports.
Please advise How to execute multiple "docker run" commands from single docker file with different ports.

Comment: Look up `docker-compose`.

Comment: Your understanding of this seems flawed. You start docker containers from an image, not a file. However, you're probably looking for the -p switch on the command line. So, `docker run --name thing1 -p 8080:8080 container`, and `docker run --name thing2 -p 8090:8080 container`.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) it sounds like. Here is an example using nginx and redis (It's how I do it anyway)

`services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "1000:1000"`

So as you can see, if I run docker-compose up, docker will spin up two containers, nginx and redis, each running off of a different port! If you don't want to you docker-compose, you can do it from docker run

`docker run --name nginx -p 1000:10001`

`docker run --name redis -p 3333:2423`

I don't 100% understand your question, but I hope this helps!